# Parsing JSON items using Angular

Tags: json, angular

I have a `JSON` object and I want to give the values of the properties to 4 of my variables using `Angular`, which are the following:

```
authorText : string;
titleText : string;
durationText : string;
genreText : string;
```

And here is the `JSON`:

```
"{"n":{  
   "_id":1101,
   "labels":[  
      "Song"
   ],
   "properties":{  
      "duration":"214000",
      "author":"Shawn Mendes",
      "genre":"pop",
      "title":"In My Blood"
   }
}
}"
```

I tried using this and similar solutions to this:

```
Object.keys(editData).forEach(function (key) {
  console.log(key);
  if(key === "author"){
     this.authorText = editData[key];
  }
  console.log( key , editData[key] );
});
```

But the key is always 0 for some reason.

**EDIT**
Added the image of the `JSON`:
The string I printed before was done as following : Saving it as global variable and then using `JSON.stringify(temp1);`.

[image]

Comment: Try with `Object.keys(editData.n.properties).forEach...`

Comment: I get this when I try to do it `TS2339: Property 'n' does not exist on type 'any[]'`

Comment: Your JSON looks malformed in that case. Please log the JSON to the console and add the exact structure of the JSON. Maybe add an image of the console log of `editData` to the question.

Comment: @SiddAjmera edited the question

Comment: Looks like your objects is contained in an array. You would need to iterate through that array to access `n`, if you are sure it's a single object in that array you can just do `editData[0].n.properties`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```
const { duration, author, genre, title } = this.editData[0].n.properties;
this.song = {
    authorText: author,
    titleText: title,
    durationText: duration,
    genreText: genre
};
```

Here, we're `destructuring` the properties from the `properties` key and just assigning them to the song Object's keys one by one.

---

**A better thing to do** would be just to name the fields as `duration`, `author`, `genre`, and `title`. Then you can simply do something like this:

```
export interface Song {
  author: string;
  title: string;
  duration: string;
  genre: string;
}
```

And in your function:

```
this.song = { ...editData[0].n.properties };
```

Here, we're using the spread operator(`...`) to spread the properties object's keys and assign them to the `song` property on your Component Class.

---

[**Here's a Sample StackBlitz for your ref.**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9qgojz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Looks like you and I are on the same wave length. :-)

Comment: Indeed! :D I got some help from your stackblitz implementation though. Didn't took much time to just wrap the object around in an array. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can just do this:

```
this.song = this.editData.n.properties;
```

I have a stackblitz demonstrating it here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-udmdqr

The basic code is here:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `<h1>Hello {{song.author}}!</h1>`,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})
export class HelloComponent {
  song: Song;
  editData = {
    "n": {
      "_id": 1101,
      "labels": [
        "Song"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "duration": "214000",
        "author": "Shawn Mendes",
        "genre": "pop",
        "title": "In My Blood"
      }
    }
  }

  constructor() {
    this.song = this.editData.n.properties;
  }
}

export interface Song {
  duration: string;
  author: string;
  genre: string;
  title: string
}
```

Comment: I edited the question because the `n` throws an error - `TS2339: Property 'n' does not exist on type 'any[]'`